# Azure AD for Staff Login and Azure B2C for Customer Login in one ASP.Net Application

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC application which will handle two types of users

1. External Users (Need to authenticate using Azure B2C with username as login instead of email as login)
2. Internal Users (which already exist in Corporate Azure AD)

What is the right way of implementing it?

One option is to run two separate instances of the application configured against each IDP. Keep each type of user stick to one app instance.

I tried to register AD and AD B2C in one app by registering two OpenIdConnect services but having problems when the user tries to access a resource without first logging into the application. Without knowing the type of the user I cannot specify AuthenticationSchema in the Authorize tag.

I am sure people have done this before so if you someone who knows how to do it, then please guide me..

Comment: Right, you can't know which IdP to redirect to since they are not authenticated. Actually in this case you can't do it for them. It would be better to instead give a choice to the user. Another option might be to bind two different subdomains to the app and redirect based on that.

Comment: thanks juunas, thats a good idea and will save me having multiple instances of the application. I also found this, haven't tried this yet but will give it ago and update my findings https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom